# Why the "or" and "|" operators share the same "__or__" magic method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that the `|` and the `or` operators have different meaning and behaviours in python. E.g:

```
>>> s1 = {1, 2, 3}
>>> s2 = {10, 20, 30}
>>> s1 or s2
{1, 2, 3}
>>> s1 | s2
{1, 2, 3, 20, 10, 30}
```

But both operators share the same `__or__` and `__ror__` magic methods. Why?

Comment: They don't. `or` has no magic hook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `or` short-circuits, there is *no* magic hook method for that operator. The same applies to `and`.

In other words, `__or__`, `__ror__` and `__ior__` are *only used for bitwise `|`*. Similarly, `__and__`, `__rand__`, and `__iand__` are only used for bitwise `&`.